# ld linker's output executable is bigger than the golink output executable, why?

Tags: windows, assembly, linker, nasm, ld

I've assembled a simple code with `nasm` and linked output obj file with both `ld` and `golink`
The issue is
golink output executable is `2kb` of size
but 
ld output executable is `85kb` of size

I'm using mingw32 and both are using the library `kernel32.dll`.

linking commands are:

```
golink /entry _start /console test.obj kernel32.dll
```

&

```
gcc test.obj-L kernel32.dll
```

So why is this huge difference in sizes?

Am I doing something wrong? Could you enlighten me please.

Comment: You are probably linking with the C librrary, try `gcc -nostdlib`.

Comment: with -nostdlib option the file size became down to 5.02kb...
But with -nostdlib option will I be able to use functions like _printf ?

Comment: Functions like _printf are part of the C standard library and it is not possible to use them without linking against C standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hit 2KB executable size with GCC, run this:

```
gcc test.obj -nostartfiles -s
```

GCC contains more data within the executable by default, compared to GoLink linker. A simple `gcc` command contains a symbol table, relocation information and some other references. We use the `-s` flag to remove the symbol table and relocation information, and `-nostartfiles` flag to stop using the standard system startup files (which reference other stuff).